# Locating IP addresses in Wireshark Traffic for Bit Torrent

Tags: ip-address, wireshark, bittorrent

I have captured some WiFi traffic on my own network using Wireshark and I am looking for a way to be able to identify the IP addresses of the peers that I have interacted with during a BitTorrent/TCP connection.
So far I have been able to pinpoint the website and the files downloaded from that website. Is there a particular filter I can in Wireshark to be able to identify the peers (ie. the IP addresses) that were in the swarm for downloading the file or would this data only contain the information of the tracker that was used please?

Kind regards,

CG.

Comment: I suggest you read about the BitTorrent protocol itself: http://www.dandylife.net/docs/BitTorrent-Protocol.pdf

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you

Comment: Do you have reassembly enabled in the BitTorrent and TCP protocol settings in wireshark? You'll also have to disable encryption in the bittorrent client since otherwise wireshark can't identify the traffic.